# Enable and disable input text while clicking on same button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I want to enable the input text by clicking on edit button and if I click again on that edit button, the input text should be in disable mode. I am able to enable but how to disable. here is my code:

```
<script>
function toggle(){

        document.getElementById("Name").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("email").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("contact").disabled = false; 
            }

</script>

<form>
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
            name="name" id="Name" maxlength="30" value="<?=$name; ?>" disabled/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="pan" id="pan" value="<?=$pan; ?>" disabled />

<input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" id="email" value="<?=$email; ?>" disabled />                                                               

<input type="number" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="contact" maxlength="10" value="<?=$mobile; ?>" disabled /> 


<input type="button" name="edit" id="edt" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button" value="Edit" 
    onclick="toggle()" >    
</form>
```

please suggest what i have to make changes in the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.getElementById('btnid').disabled is not working in firefox and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737512/document-getelementbyidbtnid-disabled-is-not-working-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you simply need to invert the current value of the `disabled` property on the required elements. To do that, use the `!` operator before the current setting, like this:

```js
function toggle() {
  document.getElementById("Name").disabled = !document.getElementById("Name").disabled;
  document.getElementById("pan").disabled = !document.getElementById("pan").disabled;
  document.getElementById("email").disabled = !document.getElementById("email").disabled;
  document.getElementById("contact").disabled = !document.getElementById("contact").disabled;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="Name" maxlength="30" value="<?= $name; ?>" disabled/>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pan" id="pan" value="<?= $pan; ?>" disabled />
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" id="email" value="<?= $email; ?>" disabled />
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="contact" maxlength="10" value="<?= $mobile; ?>" disabled />
  <input type="button" name="edit" id="edt" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button" value="Edit" onclick="toggle()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button value="false"></button>
```

```js
$('#btn_pause_resume').click(function () {
    if ($(this).data('value')==='false') {
        alert('Resumed...');
        $(this).data('value', 'true');
    } else {
        alert('Paused...');
        $(this).data('value', 'false');
    }
});
```

try this out you should get the idea

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with enabling/disabling elements...?

Comment: this shows you how to control events with same button you can dissable and enable inside that for example insted of ALERT statment , you enable the element

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way. Ask if the element is disabled or not and then set the disabled value based on that.

```js
function toggle() {

  document.getElementById("Name").disabled = document.getElementById("Name").disabled ? false : true;
  document.getElementById("email").disabled = document.getElementById("email").disabled ? false : true;
  document.getElementById("contact").disabled = document.getElementById("contact").disabled ? false : true;
  document.getElementById("pan").disabled = document.getElementById("pan").disabled ? false : true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="Name" maxlength="30" value="<?=$name; ?>" disabled/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="pan" id="pan" value="<?=$pan; ?>" disabled />

<input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" id="email" value="<?=$email; ?>" disabled />

<input type="number" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="contact" maxlength="10" value="<?=$mobile; ?>" disabled />


<input type="button" name="edit" id="edt" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button" value="Edit" onclick="toggle()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggle() {
  var enable = (this.disabled);
  document.getElementById("Name").disabled = enable;
  document.getElementById("pan").disabled = enable
  document.getElementById("email").disabled = enable;
  document.getElementById("contact").disabled = enable;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="Name" maxlength="30" value="<?=$name; ?>" disabled/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="pan" id="pan" value="<?=$pan; ?>" disabled />

<input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" id="email" value="<?=$email; ?>" disabled />

<input type="number" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="contact" maxlength="10" value="<?=$mobile; ?>" disabled />


<input type="button" name="edit" id="edt" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button" value="Edit" onclick="toggle()">
```

Comment: Thank you @vicky patel, but you are only enabling the text but not disabling the text. Rory McCrossan and Carsten Løvbo Andersen code is working according to my requirement. You too can check it once.