# Which method should I use to disabled a button

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

This is JS code for number validation,when number length is equal to 9 or 10 button is disabled and it only works when I write something into the input form because of "keyup" method.On the beggining of the script I wrote than button should be disabled but it doesnt work,he is enabled when I enter site.

```
 add_shortcode('custom_js_for_cf7','custom_js_for_cf7');
       function custom_js_for_cf7($args){
       return 
      <script>
      document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("numertel").addEventListener("keyup", 
      function() {
          var numerlength = this.value.length;
          if (numerlength == 10 || numerlength == 9)
            document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = false;
          else
            document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = true;
        });
        </script>
        ';
        }
```

Which method should I use to make button disabled when I enter the site?I tried onload and load but it doesn't work too.

Comment: C'mon, leave just the javascript part. We don't need the whole Wordpress function wrapper.

Comment: if this have to be disabled when you enter the site why not to hard code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wrote than button should be disabled but it doesnt work,he is
>   enabled when I enter site.

Put disabling part in the `DOMContentLoaded` **event listener** of the `document`.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the element with the id the attribute "disabled
. See the following link, it's a similar problem:

[document.getElementById('btnid').disabled is not working in firefox and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737512/document-getelementbyidbtnid-disabled-is-not-working-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this

```
add_shortcode('custom_js_for_cf7','custom_js_for_cf7');
function custom_js_for_cf7($args){
return '
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = true;
});
document.getElementById("numertel").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var numerlength = this.value.length;
  if (numerlength>8 && numerlength<16)
    document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = false;
  else
    document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = true;
});

</script>
';
}
```

And it broke my site,500 error so I deleted this line from ftp.Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess this is because of `'DOMContentLoaded'`, replace since quotes with double. check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote than button should be disabled but it doesnt work

Use pure HTML to disable the button

```
<button type="submit" id="przycisk" disabled="disabled">Your Button</button>
```

Comment: In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the disabled attribute must be defined as `disabled="disabled"`