# disabled={true} HTML button attribute does not work right in JavaScript + React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Having issues with disabled={true} HTML button. App is in JavaScript + React. I set button initial value `disabled={true}` .For example purposes I will call it id="button1". Once I click another button let's say id=button2, I re-enable my `button1` with code `document.getElementById('button1').disabled=false;`. Button re-enables but once clicked it has no functionality, it looks like it is still disabled. What am I doing wrong ?

OK here is my simplified code:

```
 function App() {

  const approve = () => {
    console.log('test');
    
  };

  const filterWeek2 = () => {
    document.getElementById('approve').removeAttribute("disabled");
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
          <nav>
            <ul className="nav-area">
              <li><button id="Week2" onClick={filterWeek2}>WEEK 2</button></li>
              <li><button id="approve" onClick={approve} disabled="disabled">APPROVE</button></li> 
            </ul>            
          </nav>    
        </div>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11737624/12104850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) is a boolean attribute, Its presence on an HTML elements disables the element. If it is present on the element, it will disable the HTML element, doesn't matter what value it has.

You have to remove the attribute using `removeAttribute` to make it editable

```js
const disabled = document.querySelector(".disabled");
const normal = document.querySelector(".normal");

normal.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (disabled.hasAttribute("disabled")) disabled.removeAttribute("disabled");
  else disabled.setAttribute("disabled", true);
})
```

```html
<button disabled class="disabled">button</button>
<button class="normal">toggle</button>
```

Since you are using React, then you can toggle `disabled` using state. [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-dream-okryw?file=/src/App.js:531-548)

```
disabled={active}
```

If `active` is `true` then the HTML element is disable else enabled.

Comment: still does not work.

Comment: add your code in the question.

Comment: Added the code snippet

Comment: @Min Updated answer with [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-dream-okryw?file=/src/App.js:531-548) link